# Why did relations between the USA and the USSR break down in 1945?

Tags: united-states

Could it be the USA and USSR had different post-war aims, the USA and USSR both broke promises which contributed to the breakdown in their relationship? Or could it be that the USA and USSR had major ideological differences the USA and USSR believed there could only be one superpower in the world?

Comment: What do you already know about their history? Have you read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_Union%E2%80%93United_States_relations) on relations between USSR-USA?

Comment: Relations were, to put it mildly, strained well before 1945. The only thing keeping them cooperating was that both had a minor disagreement with Japan and Germany called World War 2.

Comment: I wonder if the USSR's commitment to worldwide revolution and the overthrow of all non-communist governments, the abolition of private property or the dictatorship of the proletariat might have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 8):

### Ideology was secondary, spheres of influence were primary reason for geostrategic rivalry

Before WW2 both the US and the Soviet Union were more regional than global powers. The US had great influence in North and South America ([Monroe Doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monroe_Doctrine)), but almost no political influence in Europe, and only limited influence in Asian Pacific region due to other powers like Great Britain and Japan. TheSoviet Union, as the only socialist country, had some global influence through various leftist movements, but this was limited. In Europe, other powers (Great Britain, Germany, France etc ...) effectively blocked the Soviet Union, and only after the start of WW2 did the USSR managed to act locally in [Finland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_War) and Romania ([Bukovina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bukovina#Kingdom_of_Romania)). In Asia the USSR clashed with Japan over [Manchuria and Mongolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battles_of_Khalkhin_Gol), and had some influence in Central Asia.  Although across from one another at the Bering Strait, the USSR and the US didn't have much contact and were not seen as opponents despite different ideologies before WW2.

After WW2 things changed dramatically. Both Germany and Japan disappeared as great powers. France was severely weakened, and so was Great Britain (the British empire collapsed soon after.)  Although badly hurt in the war, the Soviet Union was now the undisputed victor in the eastern part of Europe, and ideologically aligned itself with numerous leftist liberation movements in Asia (themost important of these being China.)  The US became the leading power in the West and effectively succeed Great Britain. In fact, after WW2, Britain was practically unable to have an independent foreign policy (as witnessed, for example, in the [Suez Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suez_Crisis)) and become a US junior partner. During the war, Churchill and Stalin [agreed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentages_agreement) on zones of influence in post-war Europe, now British zones simply became US zones. In China, both the US and the USSR had their favorites, and the Soviets won. There were also divisions in Korea and Vietnam, which later led to wars.

Although ideology appears to be at the forefront of the conflict, in reality it was not so. For example, the US (supposedly champion of democracy) often supported various monarchs and dictators in order to thwart the Soviets. They were even ready to [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Nixon%27s_1972_visit_to_China) communist China, after the Sino-Soviet split. The Soviets, although nominally more ideological, didn't shy from helping completely anti-communist regimes when it suited them. For example, in 1980 Argentina [increased exports of food to USSR](https://www.quora.com/Did-the-Soviet-Union-help-Argentina-during-the-South-Atlantic-Conflict-in-1982), despite other countries in Western hemisphere boycotting it because of Soviet intervention in Afghanistan. To return the favor, Soviets abstained in voting for [Security Council resolution 502](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_502) and allegedly [helped Argentinians](https://www.rbth.com/history/326350-soviet-satellites-sink-british-warships) in the Falklands war with some recon assets.

As a conclusion, we could say that after WW2 both the US and the Soviet Union became global powers with conflicting interests in various parts of the world. As other countries joined one or the other side conflict intensified and became the Cold War. Ideology was an important part of this, but it was not the deciding factor - after all, Russia is no longer a socialist country, yet it is again opposed to the US, although ideologically and culturally much closer to it then, for example, the US ally Saudi Arabia. Rather than that, strategic interests decide who would be ally and who would be foe.

Comment: Just plain wrong.  Ideology was the only real reason for conflict: there was no real conflict between the US and other post-WWII powers (European, Japan, &c), while those other powers were in conflict with the USSR and other Communist countries.

Comment: @jamesqf Nope. Conflict endured even after the fall of communism, as soon as Russia emerged as great power again. There were no other great powers after WW2, only US and USSR. Countries in US sphere of interests became anti-communist , and those in USSR sphere communist, with notable exceptions mentioned in my answer. But if both US and Russia were capitalistic after WW2, there would still be conflict between them over influence in Europe and elsewhere .

Comment: Not so.  The conflict between the US and USSR ended with the demise of the USSR.  There was a period of a couple of decades in which there was essentially no conflict, and a degree of cooperation, for instance the ISS.  The growth of a new, smaller-scale, and very different is due to Putin and nis neo-imperialist ambitions.  You also have the US sphere thing backwards: countries didn't become anti-communist because they were in the "US sphere", they were in that sphere  BECAUSE they were anti-communist.

Comment: @jamesqf Nope. There was some easing in relations when Russia was weak during 90's , but even then West supported for example Chechen rebels. And even then NATO bases popped around Russian borders. As soon as Russia became somewhat stronger it was again enemy No 1.  And accusing Russia for neo-imperialism while supporting what US does is hypocritical. As for countries in US sphere, in many of them leftist and communist movements were forcibly removed to insure that country in question remains in US sphere .

Comment: Also consuming half of Poland.

Comment: @Spencer Actually, no. By the time WW2 started everyone (including UK) agreed that Poland took more then fair share in roaring 1920's . Specifically, they took land east of Curzon Line, with ethnically Ukrainian and Belarus population. In any case, Poland was to be compensated with German territory westward after the war, so this was not major concern. Major concern was all East European countries coming into Soviet sphere of influence.

Answer (score 6):

The USA (democracy) and the USSR (communist) were diametrically opposite of each other. They had very little in common. Very different ideas how the economy should work.

Their alliance was one of necessity. They needed each other to defeat the Axis powers. Once that was achieved, it was a matter of time before they became political enemies.

The Americans send an [expeditionary force to Siberia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Expeditionary_Force,_Siberia) in 1918. They withdrew that force in 1920. Mainly because the communists had won the civil war. The relations between the two were not 'the best of friends' to say the least in the 30's.

Comment: Not "a matter of time before they became political enemies".  They always were political enemies; the US just supplied material support to the USSR in order to defeat a common foe.

Comment: @jamesqf I fully agree with you, and can add the USA had intervened in the Russian revolution - but that is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @jamesqf, not "just". Many (if not most) of the Soviet flagship factories were built and/or designed by the Americans during the rapid industrialisation in the 30s. Generally, between the wars it was the UK and Germany that were considered the main enemies (as the rs.29's answer correctly states) and the prospective belligerents. Comparatively, the relationship with the US was rather business-like, if not warm. Even ideologically, the Americans had some sympathy for the Russian Revolution, being a nation of revolution itself - unlike all the Europe.

Answer (score 2):

The reason was best described in 1835 by one [Alexis de Tocqueville in "Democracy in America."](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/1265628-there-are-at-the-present-time-two-great-nations-in)

> "There are at the present time two great nations in the world, which started from different points, but seem to tend towards the same end. I allude to the Russians and the Americans...

> All other nations seem to have nearly reached their natural limits, and they have only to maintain their power; but these are still in the act of growth... The Anglo-American relies upon personal interest to accomplish his ends, and gives free scope to the unguided strength and common sense of the people; the Russian centres all the authority of society in a single arm. The principal instrument of the former is freedom; of the latter, servitude. Their starting-point is different, and their courses are not the same; yet each of them seems marked out by the will of Heaven to sway the destinies of half the globe.”

Exceptions to the above "rule" occur when the two have one or more common enemies. Up to 1945, these consisted of Germany, Italy, Japan, and a few east European nations. In the 1860s, Russia was still "smarting" from its defeat in the Crimean War by Britain, France, and others. It was then [very friendly with the United States,](https://www.rbth.com/politics_and_society/2017/08/16/what-role-did-russia-play-in-the-us-civil-war_823252) who feared British and French recognition of the Confederacy (and later sold Alaska to the reunited U.S.to create a "buffer zone" between British Canada and Siberia)

In 1945, the "common enemies" disappeared, and America and Russia reverted to the "Tocquevillian" order. They will become friendly again if and when there is a common "third" enemy (e.g. China).